# html to text: moving on line everything after tab to new line

Tags: python, html, text

I am using beautifulsoup to convert html to text. Everything after 1 tab is being moved to a new line and I am not sure why?

For example:

> November 5,
>
> 2008

is how

> November 5, 2008

is saved.

Code:

`soup=BeautifulSoup(download_target.text, 'html.parser')`

`f_text=soup.get_text()`

`text_file = open(file_loc+"\\"+url_rename[2]+"\\"+url_rename[3]+"\\"+url_rename[1]+".txt","w")`

`text_file.write(str(f_text.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')).replace("\\t", "").replace("\\n", "\n\r"))`

This is my first post. Sorry I am not sure how to properly format my posts.

Any idea how to put the "2008" on the first line would be much appreciated.

Ashish:

Is this what you meant:

`text_file.write(str(f_text.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')).replace("\\t", "").replace("\\n", "\n\r").join(f_text.splitlines()))`

If that is right, I get an error. Maybe I am misunderstanding your code?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you share the code snippet you're using?

Comment: text_file.write(str(f_text.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')).replace("\\t", "").replace("\\n", "\n\r"))

Comment: edit your question and post the snippet you've tried

Comment: still unclear where it's going wrong. can you share more info? perhaps the input html and a larger part of the code snippet?

Comment: if removing the `\n`s is an issue, you can try `''.join(text.splitlines())`